# Woocommerce shop page redirects to wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

At some point, the shop page started to redirect to the `wp-admin` (admin backend) page. I don't know why.

Commonly proposed solutions include:

1. Delete the shop page, and add it again using the WC > Status > Tools > Create default WooCommerce pages.
2. Make sure the WP URLs are set correctly.

Neither had any effect. The shop page URL is currently at https://website.com/?page_id=88, reflecting the number of times I tried remaking default pages.

I have also tried adding some text to the page, though it should normally be empty. This had no effect.

Ran out of ideas to try. The rest of the website mostly works.

Possibly related annoyance bug: the shop automatically adds the first product to the cart whenever one visits the site. Somewhat annoying, but not disastrous.

Versions:

- WooCommerce 3.2.6
- Wordpress 4.9.1

Comment: not really a programming question, but a support request for a third party app

Comment: Might be a programming issue. There are currently ~30k questions about woocommerce on SO, so it doesn't seem out of place.

Comment: you already know the answer, it is a config issue

Comment: I don't know the answer. I only found a workaround.

Comment: you posted an answer; if it's not the answer it should be part of the question; if it is the answer accept it and move on.

Answer (score 0):

The bug seems to be fixed by changing the Home page to the Shop page in the WP settings > reading.

[image]

Unfortunately, this workaround doesn't fix the underlying issue entirely because the bug resurfaces if one selects the front page instead of the shop as the home page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to add a question/comment, so I'll try to add this as an answer...

If you are using IIS and have setup your site as a virtual application, this may cause this error.  I had this same thing during testing.  Once I created the website as it's own proper website and accessed it properly, this fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and fixed it clearing browser cache
I hope it helps